# ASP.NET: Counting Checkbox Controls, based on CSS Class or another ID field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to count all the checkbox controls on a page, I'd like to be able to count them based on what css class they are (or any other ID field I can use to group ValidationGroup, etc). I'm still pretty green to c#. Here's my code:

```
    protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numCbSelected = 0;
        foreach (CheckBox cb in Page.Controls)
        {
            numCbSelected = numCbSelected + 1;
        }
        errLabel.Text = numCbSelected.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do some form of recursion to get all the checkboxes on the page

```
private int CountCheckboxes(Control control)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = control as CheckBox;

        int count = 0;

        if (checkBox != null)
        {
            if(checkBox.CssClass == "SomeClass")
                count++;
        }

        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            count += CountCheckboxes(child);
        }

        return count;
    }
```

Then call it

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numCbSelected = CountCheckboxes(Page)
    errLabel.Text = numCbSelected.ToString();
}
```

Comment: But keep in mind that `CssClass` refers to *all* of the classes assigned to that check box. You should probably check if the CssClass string contains "SomeClass" as a whole word rather than check equality.

Comment: Lourens & Justin, thanks a ton. Changing using Lourens' code with (checkBox.CssClass.Contains("guarCB")) worked.

Answer (score -1):

CSS is a client side technology. If you want to count the checkboxes via CSS anything, it has to be done on the client side (i.e. JavaScript). I don't think you can use the foreach you have in your code. At best, it would make all controls a checkbox (maybe they are?) and at worst fail.

Loop through the controls in Page.Controls. Then check the type of control. Without actually coding, it is something like:

```
foreach(Control cb in Page.Controls)
{
   if(cb.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
   {   //do something here
   }
}
```

this is rough and you may have to tweak it, but you can set up your count this way.